# Querying remote sqlite database

Tags: c#, database, sqlite

Symantec backup software writes backup image details to a local Sqlite database.  I'm writing a utility to query several of these databases on multiple devices from a central location.  I only need the most recently added records from a single table in each database.

<strike>However, based on the network traffic I'm observing, it appears that the entire database is being transferred across the network.</strike>  However, based on procmon results, it appears that all 4,920 records in the table are being transferred across the network.  **Is there a way to pull just the records I need?**  Perhaps one must sort by an index to avoid pulling over all records?

I should be seeing just a few KB of data transfer, but instead I'm seeing several MB per query.  I know it is possible to transfer just the records you need with MS Access databases--which are also file-based--but I don't have much experience with sqlite.

I'm open to more creative solutions as well.

Comment: Show the DB schema and the query. Are there indexes?

Comment: The table needed to be indexed.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

I had to fix two things to reduce the amount of network traffic generated by my sqlite queries:

1. Add an index that matched the `ORDER BY` clause of my query
2. Add a `LIMIT` clause to my query so that I was only pulling the records I actually needed